# Using an external typescript class without importing it

Tags: typescript

For example, I have a class called Constant

I want this class to be used anywhere without being imported, is that possible?

in constant.ts

```
 class Constant {
       public static get TOTAL_FOOD() : number {return 123;}
 }
```

in chicken.ts

```
 class Chicken {

      constructor() {
          // i want to calll constant without importing it like import {Constant} 
          let totalFood : number = Constant.TOTAL_FOOD;

      }
 }
```

Comment: Please provide more detail, preferrably with some sample code.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, i have updated it

Comment: Where do you plan to run it? Is it a browser app or node app? If it's a browser app, how are you loading your scripts? Are you using a module system (requirejs, systemjs, etc) or with `script` tags?

Comment: i used requirejs, in the browser, no script tags

Answer (score 0):

In your example you are defining the class to hold some constants. In these cases I usually use a namespace that allows me to access the constants anywhere:

```
namespace Constant {
    export const TOTAL_FOOD: 123;
}
```

In case you use classes, you can mark them with the `export` keyword to make them accessible outside the file they are defined in:

```
export class Constant {
    public static get TOTAL_FOOD() : number {return 123;}
}
```

Comment: what if i want to add it to the namespace

Comment: for example
import {something} from Constants.LOC + "something";

Comment: You can spread your namespace over multiple files. As long as you define the `Constant` class as `export`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use requirejs to load this file then there's no way to use it without importing it.

What you can do however is to load just this file using a script tag instead of using requirejs.
So in your html you'll have:

```
<script src="//PATH/TO/constant.js"></script>
```

In `constant.ts` don't use `export` and compile it with declaration files flag (`-d`), when you compile it you'll get:

```
declare class Constant {
    static readonly TOTAL_FOOD: number;
}
```

Then wherever you need it just do:

```
/// <reference path="PATH/TO/constant.d.ts" />

console.log(Constant.TOTAL_FOOD);
```